# Understanding of loading data in Caffe Deep Learning

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am using [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) for my deep learning application.

I know how to prepare data to LMDB format and prepare data and prototxt files.
One of the discussions on Internet can be found [here](https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/using-caffe-with-your-own-dataset-b0ade5d71233).

In Train.prototxt file there is a path for `train lmdb`, for example `examples/dogs/dogs_train_lmdb`.

What I like to see is how `bounding boxes in label text files` and `jpeg images` are made sure as those `bounding boxes are from correct image`?

Which file of `Caffe` has that implementation?

My thinking is that there should be a place to read file name, then using that file name correct images and bounding boxes in label text files are loaded.

That is what I think, but how it is actually implemented in Caffe is the information that I am curious.

Comment: I don't think "basic" caffe has an input layer supporting bboxes for object detection training. You should look at [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) reposidtory, or [faster RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) repository for examples.

Comment: @Shai thank you. SSD has how to load Annotated data and images implemented in `void AnnotatedDataLayer<Dtype>::load_batch(Batch<Dtype>* batch)`. But i can't find where they are synchornized for the loaded Bounding Boxes are from the respective image. Do you have any idea?